# Windows track of the files opened histroy

Tags: windows

I have requirement where in I need to keep the track of the files that are opened for months in windows, I know 'RecentItems' max keeps 30 most recent files opened history. I want keep the history of month.

Please suggest if any software is available for this requirement ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could run this [command line handle viewer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896655) at regular intervals to check what files are open and then process the results yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think this tool provides the details of the files that currently opened by all process in the system. I want some tool which shows files opened in the past also.